# batch script issue while updating the output text file string as command line argument

Tags: shell, batch-file

Iam new to bach script. following is the code i used to search the name entered through command line and search the entered string in outputLog.txt .if found update the current system time of that name string.

In command line
[root@localhost desktop]# ./myscript.sh name1

```
Logone2.txt
name1 = Tue Jan  20 14:00 19 IST 2012 
name2 =Tue Jan  20 14:05 19 IST 2012 
name3 = Tue Jan  20 14:20 19 IST 2012 
name4 =Tue Jan 20 14:45 19 IST 2012
```

My problem is while i trying to enter name1,it is updated with the current system time also its is appending as last entry.

```
 Eg:Logone2.txt
    name1 = Tue Feb    20 14:00 19 IST 2012 
    name2 =Tue Jan  20 14:05 19 IST 2012 
    name3 = Tue Jan  20 14:20 19 IST 2012 
    name4 =Tue Jan 20 14:45 19 IST 2012
    name1 = Tue Feb    20 14:00 19 IST 2012 (appended entry)
```

I only want to append the string with current system time if it is not found in the Logone2.txt.IF the string(name1) entered  through command line is found in the Logone2.txt ,update the name with current system time as follows.

```
  Eg:Logone2.txt
name1 = Tue Feb    20 14:00 19 IST 2012 
name2 =Tue Jan  20 14:05 19 IST 2012 
name3 = Tue Jan  20 14:20 19 IST 2012 
name4 =Tue Jan 20 14:45 19 IST 2012
```

Here is the code iam using

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "${1} $(date)" >> /root/Desktop/scripts/Logone2.txt
fgrep "${1}" /root/Desktop/scripts/Logone2.txt && \ 
     sed -i "/${1}/ s/.*/${1} = $(date)/" /root/Desktop/scripts/Logone2.txt || \
echo "${1} $(date)" >> /root/Desktop/scripts/Logone2.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i got it right my first idea is to rewrite the entire file replacing name1 with sed. e.g.

```
cat Logone2.txt | sed "s/^name1=.*/name1=`date`/g" > newfile.txt
```